# Simpler Way to Draw Lines on TableLayoutPanel of Labels?

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

My picture shows a TableLayoutPanel filled with labels.  I want to draw a box around one of the rows in the table as shown in this picture:

[image: TableLayoutPanel with lines]

It took 5 event handlers to achieve this!  I am drawing lines in each of the 4 Paint event handlers for the labels, and then I draw lines in the TableLayoutPanel Paint event handler to connect the lines drawn by the labels Paint events.

Does it really need to be this complicated?  If I try to draw everything in the TableLayoutPanel Paint event handler only, it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's that complicated.  Looking at your output though, it looks like a job for the DataGridView control more than the TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Rather than drawing a box around a row to highlight it, maybe it would be better to simply assign a different background colour to the row instead?

Comment: @LarsTech - can the DataGridView be created with column names only?  I started with that control, but it seemed to want row labels as well.

Comment: RowHeadersVisible = False

Comment: @Zaf Khan - Hmmm...maybe...let me see how that looks.

Comment: Another even simpler alternative is to use a SHAPE control and simply MOVE it to the row you want highlighted.

Comment: @ Zaf Khan - By SHAPE control, you mean a RectangleShape?  I tried using that, but I could never get it to stay in front of the labels: no matter how many times I called its BringToFront method or how many times I called everything else's SendToBack methods.  I tried making setting its parent to the TableLayoutPanel and the GroupBox.  Was there something I missed with that method?